# How can I do this using arraylist or array?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add some string names to stars arraylist using addStar function in Star class. 
But I am encountering an error like this:

> The method add(Star) in the type arraylist is not applicable for this arguments.

Eclipse says to me the string parameter is not acceptable, so how can i do this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Star { 
    public static String name; 
    public static ArrayList<Star> stars=new ArrayList<>();     

    public Star(String name) {  
        this.name=name;     
    }

    public static void addStar(String name) {   
        stars.add(name);     
    }    
}
```

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory. Please explain your specific question.

Comment: Why on earth did you make `name` static? You only have one `name` for all stars? And what about `stars`? Should it hold `Star`(s) or names? And when you add a `Star`, are you adding a `String`?

Comment: i used static because i m trying to add some Stars names without creating objects.

Comment: Go back and read the documentation again. Your code isn't going to work. You can't add `Star` instances to a `List<Star>` without creating objects.

Comment: i am sorry i am so confused.


public class Star {
public static String name;
public static ArrayList<Star> stars=new ArrayList<>();


public Star(String name) {
 this.name=name;
 }

public static void addStar(String name) {
 Star s1=new Star(name);
 stars.add(s1);

}

}

now its true but. 
on main if i write addStar("some name") 
i ve got stars(0) now but when i try to second addition with addStar("some second name")  i losed old stars(0). how can do without losing stars(0) and continuous addition process? i hope i can ask my problem now

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your error is because you made `name` to be `static`. Since you made `name` to be `static`, it means that name can hold one and only one thing. So every time you make a new Star object, the value of `name` will change to whatever the latest Star object holds, and so will have the appearance of "losing stars", as you said, because since `name` is `static`, there can only ever be one name.

The corrected code should be

```
public class Star { 
public String name; 
public static ArrayList<Star> stars=new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String [] args) {
    addStar("some name");
    addStar("some second name");
    System.out.println(stars);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Star(String name) { 
    this.name=name; 
    } 

public static void addStar(String name) { 
    Star s1=new Star(name); 
    stars.add(s1); 
    } 

public String toString() {
    String res = "";
        res+=getName();
    return res;
}

}
```

As you can see, I made a `toString()` method. In the `main` method, when printing out 
`stars`, it automatically calls `toString()`, but here I override the default `toString()` method
so that the `stars` ArrayList will print out in the way we want, as the default way will
just print out the location in memory where the objects are stored. If you have any 
questions, go ahead and ask.